# Latex Error: File 'multirow.sty' not found , Enter file name:

Tags: xetex

I got this error with Latex and it was right after installing XeLaTex to make a graphic.
Here is my code (the essential) :

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, multirow, makecell}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/coco/Desktop/School/TM/Ts_temps.pdf}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx} 


\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Can anybody know how to fix it ?

Comment: Did you check whether it's installed?

Comment: Exactly how did you install latex?

Comment: That could mean that the package is not in your hard disk (not installed, deleted, corrupted) or is not in a searchable path (not well installed). I will start by check if the file exist in your yard disk. BTW, if you are using MikTeK,  that install packages automatically by demand,  probably this will be solved next time that you try to use the package, but be patient if you have still a basic installation with few packages.